# nullpointerexception array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

So, I've been pondering why my code hasn't been working all night and after ages of searching with no cure I decided to post here. I'm receiving an NPE on the line with:

```
this.numbers[a][b] = new Integer(n[a][b]);
```

With this being my full code:

```
private int[][] numbers, temp, temp2;
private int a, b;

public Matrix(int[][] n)
{
System.out.println(n[0].length);
int numbers[][] = new int[n[0].length][n[1].length];
int temp[][] = new int[n[0].length-1][n[1].length-1];
int temp2[][] = new int[n[0].length][n[1].length];
    for(a=0;a<n[0].length;a++)
        for(b=0;b<n[1].length;b++)
        {
            this.numbers[a][b] = new Integer(n[a][b]);
            this.temp2[a][b] = new Integer(n[a][b]);
        }
    this.xLength = n[0].length;
    this.yLength = n[1].length;
}
```

I'm clueless on why I get an error; though I'm sure it's a simple mistake. Help appreciated. (n[][] is a perfectly fine array)

Comment: I got the same error with [[4, 1], [7, 1]]

Comment: `new Integer(n[a][b])` with that, your object is immediately auto-unboxed and discarded for good. I don't understand why you are doing that.

Comment: = new Integer(n[a][b]); and = n[a][b]; are no different. I was just desperate to see if it'd work.

Comment: Initialize your global variables or remove the "this" inside the function. Those solutions worked for me. btw Im assuming your code dont have syntax error, cause the one you posted has. :)

Comment: I removed the this. from the numbers and it worked, tyvm!

Answer (score 2):

numbers is an array that is defined inside your method, not inside the class you have, so this.numbers refers to the array that you have defined inside your class (which admittedly has the value null), not the local numbers array you have defined in your method.

Comment: changing `numbers` to `this.numbers` in the second line of your method will fix the issue, but I'm not sure if that's the optimal solution for your case. You should consider whether 'numbers' is an array that you want to keep alive after the execution of your method has finished.

Comment: I suppose it would have been useful to say I'd defined them in the line just above my method; that's not the issue, and adding a this.number made java syntax angry

Answer (score 0):

Something I notice right off the bat:  In your constructor, you're masking your three instance variables `numbers`, `temp`, and `temp2`.  You don't need to do that.

Remove the type declaration and square brackets from each of those variables and your NPE shouldn't continue.  It's primarily occurring because `numbers` is `null`, and you can't dereference/index into null.

There's also little meaning in `new Integer(n[a][b]);`.  If the type of `n[i]` and `numbers[j][k]` is `int[]` (that is, primitive `int`), then you don't need to do any autoboxing; just assign the value straight through.

Your loop variables (`a`, `b`) need to have `int` in front of them before they'll work the way you expect them to - otherwise they're not declared.

Lastly, you're looping over the wrong dimensions.  For looping over two-dimensional arrays whose length differs, you want to use `n.length` for the outer loop, and `n[0].length` for the inner loop.  So it'd look like this:

```
 for (int a = 0; a < n.length; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < n[0].length; b++) {
        numbers[a][b] = new Integer(n[a][b]);
        temp2[a][b] = new Integer(n[a][b]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is a type declaration? I just haven't learned the vocabulary stuff much, so I feel stupid for asking.

Comment: For example:  `int foo = 2;` - we know that `foo` has been declared the type of `int`.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks though removing the this in front of numbers fixed my error :P